# Making facebook login work with an Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, webview

I am just trying to implement the facebook login on a WebView in Android. The problem is after I click the facebook button on my HTML page and insert the username and password on Facebook dialog. The url redirect is just giving me a black page.

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);        
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());  
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.loadUrl("http://peoplehunt.crowdscanner.com/hunt"); 
    setContentView(webview);
```

This is the Facebook regular javascript API on my HTML page and this function gets called when the facebook button is clicked.

```
$("#login_facebook").click(function() {

                    FB.login(function(response) {
                            //This function should be called
                            if (response.authResponse) {
                            FB.api('/me?fields=name,email,picture,id&type=large', function(response) {
                                    //console.log("email "+response.email);
                                    $("#submitHandle").hide();
                                    $("#loader").show();
                                    //console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.picture + '.');
                                    var theUsername = response.name;
                                    theUsername = theUsername.replace(/ /g, '_')+"_"+response.id+"@meetforeal.com";
                                    //console.log(theUsername);
                                    $("input[name=email]").val(encodeURIComponent(response.email));
                                    $("input[name=lastName]").val(encodeURIComponent(response.name));
                                    $("input[name=avatarImage]").val(response.picture);
                                    $("input[name=userName]").val(encodeURIComponent(theUsername));
                                    $("#msg_twitter").fadeIn("slow");
                                    $("#submitHandle").show();
                                    $("#loader").hide();
                                    $("#user").attr("action","/crowdmodule/auth/registerattendeefacebook");
                                    $("#user").submit();
                            });
                            } else {
  //console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
 }
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

ANY ideas on how to get the response back after the redirect on the Facebook dialog page? THANKS.

Answer (score 49):

I had the same issue on my android application.
The cause of the issue is FB login javascript opens a new page on a new window. Then it tries to close it and send some javascript auth codes back, after login success.  WebView is typically "single window only" so it has no place to go back to, hence the blank screen.

Please follow flowing example from my working codes.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".MyActivity" 
android:id="@+id/webview_frame">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

The Webview of id "webview" is the main view for my content.
Below is my activity codes.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

/* URL saved to be loaded after fb login */
private static final String target_url="http://www.example.com";
private static final String target_url_prefix="www.example.com";
private Context mContext;
private WebView mWebview;
private WebView mWebviewPop;
private FrameLayout mContainer;
private long mLastBackPressTime = 0;
private Toast mToast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_urimalo);
    // final View controlsView =
    // findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true); 
    mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    //mWebviewPop = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewPop);
    mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.webview_frame);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient());
    mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new UriChromeClient());
    mWebview.loadUrl(target_url);

    mContext=this.getApplicationContext();

}


private class UriWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
        //Log.d("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", url);
        if (host.equals(target_url_prefix)) 
        {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load
            // the page
            if(mWebviewPop!=null)
            {
                mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                mWebviewPop=null;
            }
            return false;
        }

        if(host.equals("m.facebook.com"))
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch
        // another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
            SslError error) {
        Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "onReceivedSslError");
        //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }
}

class UriChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
            boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        mWebviewPop = new WebView(mContext);
        mWebviewPop.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient());
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
        mWebviewPop.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);
        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
        Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called");
    }

}
}
```

The key for this issue is onCreateWindow. A new window is created and inserted to the frame layout and removed upon success. I added the removal at shouldOverrideUrlLoading.

Comment: The `if` condition should be `host.equals("m.facebook.com") || host.equals("www.facebook.com")` to match the case it loads www first before redirect to the mobile version.

Comment: I tried the same but I still get the blank page, any solutions ?

Comment: This brought me issues when using any links that contained `target="_blank"` - mContainer being null in some situations triggered a nullpointerexception. To solve this I simply had to replace the following line :
`mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);`
with :
`if (mContainer != null) mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);`

Comment: I haven't tested on older Android devices yet, but on API 21+ you need to add:

`if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    cookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(myWebView, true);
}`

Comment: @ken You i added above code and also if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { cookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(myWeb‌​View, true); } but still no luck

Comment: I followed this code. But no luck. FB login page appears. After entering credentials and hit login, it stuck there.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I have an issue. Everytime I click on any eternal link, there's a quick white flash then the app opens in a new browser (perfect) but when I go back to the app, it's frozen.

Comment: This solution works absolutely fine, is just that it needs 2 changes:
1. As mentioned above, add under onCreate the code:
`if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { cookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(myWebView, true); } `
2. After code above is implemented, the login will happen, but the white screen won't disappear because  `if (host.equals(target_url_prefix))` needs to be replaced with `if (host.equals(target_url_prefix) || url.contains("ret=login")) `, where "ret=login" is part of the URL page that facebook returns after login and needs to be closed.

Comment: @VivekSinha: If I disable javascript, it works. It gets stuck otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example Android project:
[Github: Android_Popup_Webview_handler_example](https://github.com/hwasiti/Android_Popup_Webview_handler_example)

This is an Android Studio project showing how to handle popups in Android Webview. 
Most open Source browsers do not support opening popups.

Popups are especially important in OAuth login used in a lot of websites (e.g., [www.feedly.com](http://www.feedly.com)). 
The popups in this project opened in a dialog and can be dismissed by a close button or pressing Back or if the popup window closes itself (like what happens on most login authentication flow).

Comment: Facebook login is working in this case. Google login has disallowed user agent issue.

Comment: @vivek Sinha that's something related to a different issue. Google stopped supporting login from webview from April 2017 onward.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding [the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20979409/2419808) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20965285/2419808), you just need to implement the onPageFinished method of the WebViewClient class that you use.

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // First, get the URL that Facebook's login button is actually redirecting you to.
    // It should be something simulator to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/arbiter?relation=opener&close=true
    String webUrl = webView.getUrl();
    // Pass it to the LogCat so that you can then use it in the if statement below.
    Log.d.println(TAG, webUrl);

    if (url.startsWith("The url that you copied from the LogCat")) {
        // Check whether the current URL is the URL that Facebook's redirecting you to.
        // If it is - that's it - do what you want to after the logging process has finished.
        return;
    }

    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
}
```

It worked just fine for me. Hope it helps you too :)

Answer (score 2):

Override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` in your `WebViewClient`. Search for `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`  [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html). Also, there is a parameter you can pass to facebook's login API; I think it's redirect_uri. That should help you recognize when the login is successful and in your `shouldOVerrideUrlLoading()`, you would just have to detect the url being loaded and if it is the redirect_uri you specified, then just return true in that method and close the webview or whatever you want to when the login is successful.

Answer (score 2):

Above answer is too old and it does not work with latest Facebook sdk version 2.7. After spending 4 hours on it, I have found out few changes in it. Following code will work fine with latest SDK.

Below mentioned is the XML layout file.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/webview_frame">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is the Android Activity code snippet

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private WebView mWebviewPop;
    private FrameLayout mContainer;
    private Context mContext;

    private String url = "https://www.YourWebsiteAddress.com";
    private String target_url_prefix = "www.YourWebsiteAddress.com";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Get outer container
        mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.webview_frame);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        //These two lines are specific for my need. These are not necessary
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode( WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );
        }

        //Cookie manager for the webview
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new UriWebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.YourWebsiteAddress.com");


        mContext=this.getApplicationContext();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();

            if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {

                if(Uri.parse(url).getPath().equals("/connection-compte.html")) {
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.YourWebsiteAddress.com"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);

                    return true ;
                }

                if (host.equals(target_url_prefix)) {
                    if (mWebviewPop != null) {
                        mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                        mWebviewPop = null;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                if (host.equals("m.facebook.com") || host.equals("www.facebook.com") || host.equals("facebook.com")) {
                    return false;
                }
                // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch
                // another Activity that handles URLs
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            // Otherwise allow the OS to handle it
            else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                Intent tel = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(tel);
                return true;
            }
            //This is again specific for my website
            else if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                Intent mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                mail.setType("application/octet-stream");
                String AdressMail = new String(url.replace("mailto:" , "")) ;
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ AdressMail });
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                startActivity(mail);
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "onReceivedSslError");
            //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.startsWith("https://m.facebook.com/v2.7/dialog/oauth")){
                if(mWebviewPop!=null)
                {
                    mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                    mWebviewPop=null;
                }
                view.loadUrl("https://www.YourWebsiteAddress.com");
                return;
            }
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }

private class UriWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                      boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            mWebviewPop = new WebView(mContext);
            mWebviewPop.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            mWebviewPop.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
            mWebviewPop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
            mWebviewPop.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
            Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain `/connection-compte.html`? Is this where you send your user to after login is successful from facebook?

Answer (score 2):

My answer is essentially similar to some others here, in that I create a second `WebView` to host the Facebook login page, rather than attempting to solve the problem with redirects. However, I chose to place the login `WebView` in its own `Fragment`, and give it is own dedicated `WebViewClient` and `WebChromeClient` subclasses. I think this makes it a little easier to see what role each component plays, and which objects need which settings and behaviors.

I also make use of `WebChromeClient.onCloseWindow()` to detect when Facebook's JavaScript wants to close the login window. This is much more robust than the approach I originally pursued, from a different answer.

In your `Activity` layout, you'll have the "primary" `WebView`, which hosts the comments, and a container for the `FacebookWebLoginFragment`. The login `Fragment` is created on-the-fly, when it's needed, and then removed when Facebook's login JavaScript requests that its window be closed.

My `Activity` layout looks like this:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar_common" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/web_view_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        />
    <!-- Used for Facebook login associated with comments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/facebook_web_login_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Within your `Activity`, you'll need code to show and hide the Facebook web login fragment. I use the Otto event bus, so I have event handlers like the ones below. (Nothing here is specific to this problem; I include this code just to give you a sense of how the login `Fragment` fits into the overall structure.)

```
@Subscribe
public void onShowFacebookWebLoginEvent(ShowFacebookWebLoginEvent event) {
    FacebookWebLoginFragment existingFragment = getFacebookWebLoginFragment();
    if (existingFragment == null) {
        mFacebookWebLoginFragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        createFacebookWebLoginFragment(event);
    }
}

@Subscribe
public void onHideFacebookWebLoginEvent(HideFacebookWebLoginEvent event) {
    FacebookWebLoginFragment existingFragment = getFacebookWebLoginFragment();
    if (existingFragment != null) {
        mFacebookWebLoginFragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .remove(existingFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}

@Nullable
private FacebookWebLoginFragment getFacebookWebLoginFragment() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    return (FacebookWebLoginFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.facebook_web_login_fragment_container);
}

private void createFacebookWebLoginFragment(ShowFacebookWebLoginEvent event) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FacebookWebLoginFragment fragment = (FacebookWebLoginFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.facebook_web_login_fragment_container);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = FacebookWebLoginFragment.newInstance(event.getOnCreateWindowResultMessage());
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.facebook_web_login_fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

While the `FacebookWebLoginFragment` is around, it should be given authority to handle device back-button presses. This is important because the Facebook login flow includes the ability to navigate away from the login page, and the user will expect the back button to return them to login. So, in my `Activity`, I have this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    boolean handled = false;
    FacebookWebLoginFragment facebookWebLoginFragment = getFacebookWebLoginFragment();
    if (facebookWebLoginFragment != null) {
        handled = facebookWebLoginFragment.onBackPressed();
    }
    if (!handled) {
        WebViewFragment fragment = getWebViewFragment();
        if (fragment != null) {
            handled = fragment.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    if (!handled) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

The layout for `FacebookWebLoginFragment` is extremely simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Here's the `FacebookWebLoginFragment` code. Note that it relies on a subclass of `WebChromeClient` to detect when the Facebook login JavaScript is ready to close the window (i.e., remove the fragment). Note also that there is no direct communication between this login `WebView` and the primary `WebView`, which contains the comments UI; the auth token is passed along via a third-party cookie, which is why you have to be sure to enable third-party cookie support on your primary `WebView`.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

/**
 * Hosts WebView used by Facebook web login.
 */
public class FacebookWebLoginFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private static final String LOGTAG = LogHelper.getLogTag(FacebookWebLoginFragment.class);

    @Bind(R.id.web_view) WebView mFacebookLoginWebView;

    private WebChromeClient mFacebookLoginWebChromeClient;
    private Message onCreateWindowResultMessage;

    public static FacebookWebLoginFragment newInstance(Message onCreateWindowResultMessage) {
        FacebookWebLoginFragment fragment = new FacebookWebLoginFragment();
        fragment.onCreateWindowResultMessage = onCreateWindowResultMessage;
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_facebook_web_login, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View v, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);

        mFacebookLoginWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mFacebookLoginWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mFacebookLoginWebView.setWebViewClient(new FacebookLoginWebViewClient());
        mFacebookLoginWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mFacebookLoginWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
        mFacebookLoginWebView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        mFacebookLoginWebChromeClient = makeFacebookLoginWebChromeClient();
        mFacebookLoginWebView.setWebChromeClient(mFacebookLoginWebChromeClient);

        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) onCreateWindowResultMessage.obj;
        transport.setWebView(mFacebookLoginWebView);
        onCreateWindowResultMessage.sendToTarget();
        onCreateWindowResultMessage = null; // This seems to eliminate a mysterious crash
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mFacebookLoginWebChromeClient = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**
     * Performs fragment-specific behavior for back button, and returns true if the back press
     * has been fully handled.
     */
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
            if (mFacebookLoginWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mFacebookLoginWebView.goBack();
            } else {
                closeThisFragment();
            }
            return true;
    }

    private void closeThisFragment() {
        EventBusHelper.post(new HideFacebookWebLoginEvent());
    }

    class FacebookLoginWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // Only allow content from Facebook
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            String scheme = uri.getScheme();
            if (scheme != null && (TextUtils.equals(scheme, "http") || TextUtils.equals(scheme, "https"))) {
                if (UriHelper.isFacebookHost(uri)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private WebChromeClient makeFacebookLoginWebChromeClient() {
        return new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
                closeThisFragment();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now, the trickiest bit is making the changes necessary to your existing `WebView`, since it's likely you've already got a fair amount of code in place around it, and you'll need to make sense of what needs to change.

First, make sure you have JavaScript enabled, and that it supports multiple windows.

```
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

You do *not* need to call `setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true)`.

Looking at some of the other answers, you might think you need to monkey with the `WebViewClient` that's assigned to your `WebView`, and override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`. This is not necessary. What's important is the `WebChromeClient`, which needs to override `onCreateWindow()`.

So... next, assign a custom `WebChromeClient` subclass to your `WebView`:

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        String url = null;
        Message href = view.getHandler().obtainMessage();
        if (href != null) {
            view.requestFocusNodeHref(href);
            url = href.getData().getString("url");
        }
        LogHelper.d(LOGTAG, "onCreateWindow: " + url);

        // Unfortunately, url is null when "Log In to Post" button is pressed
        if (url == null || UriHelper.isFacebookHost(Uri.parse(url))) {
            // Facebook login requires cookies to be enabled, and on more recent versions
            // of Android, it's also necessary to enable acceptance of 3rd-party cookies
            // on the WebView that hosts Facebook comments
            CookieHelper.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);

            EventBusHelper.post(new ShowFacebookWebLoginEvent(resultMsg));
        } else {
            LogHelper.d(LOGTAG, "Ignoring request from js to open new window for URL: " + url);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

You'll notice this is the second call to `UriHelper.isFacebookHost()`. I don't have a bullet-proof approach to determining this, but here's what I do:

```
public static boolean isFacebookHost(Uri uri) {
    if (uri != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(uri.getHost())) {
        String host = uri.getHost().toLowerCase();
        return host.endsWith("facebook.com") || host.endsWith("facebook.net");
    }
    return false;
}
```

You'll also notice the call to `CookieHelper.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies()`. Here's the code for that:

```
public static void setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(WebView webView, boolean accept) {
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

    // This is a safeguard, in case you've disabled cookies elsewhere
    if (accept && !cookieManager.acceptCookie()) {
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    }
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, accept);
    }
}
```

One more thing that trips some people up is the configuration of "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" in the Facebook dev settings. If you see an error like this in your logs:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

... then you'll want to check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37009374

Have fun! A complicated solution to what seems like a pretty simple problem. On the positive side, Android has given developers a ton of control here.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me! I have a LIKE, SHARE, Comments button on my page.

```kotlin
    private lateinit var myWebView: WebView;
private val target_url = "https://www.webkomph.com"
private val target_url_prefix = "webkomph.com"
private var mContext: Context? = null
private var mWebviewPop: WebView? = null
private var mContainer: ConstraintLayout? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true)

    myWebView  = findViewById(R.id.webkom_site);
    mContainer = findViewById(R.id.webview_frame);
    val webkomBlue = Color.parseColor("#1c71bc")
    myWebView.setBackgroundColor(webkomBlue);
    myWebView.background
    val webSettings = myWebView.settings;
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(UriWebViewClient())
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(UriChromeClient())
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(myWebView, true)
    }
    myWebView.loadUrl(target_url);
    mContext = this.applicationContext
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

inner class UriWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
        view: WebView,
        url: String
    ): Boolean {
        val host = Uri.parse(url).host
        //Log.d("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", url);
        if(host == null || host == target_url_prefix) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load
            // the page
            if (mWebviewPop != null) {
                mWebviewPop!!.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                mContainer?.removeView(mWebviewPop)
                mWebviewPop = null
            }
            return false
        }


        if (host == "m.facebook.com" || host == "www.facebook.com" || url.contains("ret=login")) {
            return false
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch
        // another Activity that handles URLs
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
        startActivity(intent)
        return true
    }

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String) {
        // Facebook redirects to this url once a user has logged in, this is a blank page so we override this
        // http://www.facebook.com/connect/connect_to_external_page_widget_loggedin.php?............
        if (url.contains("plugins/close_popup.php?reload") || url.contains("dialog/close_window") || url.contains("facebook.com/dialog/plugin.optin?")) {

            if(mWebviewPop != null){
                mWebviewPop!!.visibility = View.GONE
                mContainer!!.removeView(mWebviewPop)
                mWebviewPop = null
                if(myWebView != null && (url.contains("dialog/close_window") || url.contains("facebook.com/dialog/plugin.optin?"))){
                    myWebView?.reload();
                }
            }


            return
        }
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
    }
    override fun onReceivedSslError(
        view: WebView, handler: SslErrorHandler,
        error: SslError
    ) {
        Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "onReceivedSslError")
        //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }
}

inner class UriChromeClient : WebChromeClient() {
    override fun onCreateWindow(
        view: WebView, isDialog: Boolean,
        isUserGesture: Boolean, resultMsg: Message
    ): Boolean {
        mWebviewPop = WebView(mContext)
        mWebviewPop!!.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false)
        mWebviewPop!!.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false)
        mWebviewPop!!.setWebViewClient(UriWebViewClient())
        mWebviewPop!!.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
        mWebviewPop!!.getSettings().setSavePassword(false)
        mWebviewPop!!.layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
        mContainer?.addView(mWebviewPop)
        val transport = resultMsg.obj as WebViewTransport
        transport.webView = mWebviewPop
        resultMsg.sendToTarget()
        return true
    }

    override fun onCloseWindow(window: WebView) {
        Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your webview to xml layout file. The blank page error was caused due to js script fail while redirecting oAuth login to authorization acceptance page. You can overcome this issue by moving your webview into xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not an always viable answer, but another option is to switch from "popup then JS" style OAuth login to the non-popup "redirect_uri" OAUth style, where it sends them to the login page, then after success/failure they get sent to "some uri err other" (ex: another page on your own website) that completes the authentication.  FWIW.

FWIW where facebook says "if you're doing WebView redirect them to  https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" my hunch is that that's for the case of (only having a single WebView and) using OAuth to login, so they'd add some auth params to the login_success.html that you could then glean, so not the normal web flow...

Another possibility might be to [override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10037870/32453) the javascript `postMessage` function so you can capture what it was *about to* return to the parent window.