# Blank empty page in android webview after facebook login using javascript

Tags: android, facebook

i am developing a new android application,and using a webview to view my website in one the website pages there is a link for login with facebook

- after logging directly, it returns a blank and embty webview
- i have seen couple of topics here regarding the same issue but it is not exactly like mine
  please note that if i am using normal desktop browser the issue is not there

I assume that there is a property of the webview should be adjusted , below my webview code

```
webView1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
webView1.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient()); 
WebView webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView1.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView1.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webView1.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView1.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);           
webView1.loadUrl("http://www.myactivepoint.com/mobile/maplp.asp");
```

i really approciate your support

Comment: I believe it is caused by WebView being by default "single view only" see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648099/making-facebook-login-work-with-an-android-webview/19068076#19068076

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience with you. I solved the problem by the following methods.

```
public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{      
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        if(url.startsWith("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth")){
           String redirectUrl = "http://www.mydomain.com/myReturnUrl";
            view.loadUrl(redirectUrl);
           return;
       }
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }}
```

and  just add it to your WebView

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

Comment: Before you can do this you have to check this first seems to be.
(app settings->basic->Mobile Web->Enter the return_url)

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. After successfull login you have to redirect the page. You can get the address from *refsrc* parameter in the Facebook URL, but sometimes (e.g. next try to log in) refsrc is missing so I use *domain* parameter. You can override the URL address if you need. See the code:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, final String url)
    {
        if(getActivity()!=null)
        {
            if(url.contains("facebook.com") && url.contains("dialog/oauth") &&
                (url.contains("&refsrc") || url.contains("&domain")))
            {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                String callbackUrl = uri.getQueryParameter("refsrc");
                if(callbackUrl==null)
                    callbackUrl = "http://" + uri.getQueryParameter("domain");
                view.loadUrl(callbackUrl); // callback URL
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will close the permission dialog after the login