# Facebook Login inside webpage on Webview not working

Tags: android, facebook, webview, android-webview, facebook-login

I have a opening a webpage inside webview and trying to login into it using facebook login option, but failed with blank screen inside webview.

`on PageFinish()` under `WebViewClient` showing page  `https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2.........` is loaded but failed to show redirected url

I am using

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.clearCache(true);
            webView.clearHistory();
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.xyz.com/");
            webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "HTMLOUT");
```

Help it out 
Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the Facebook SDK? It'll handle logins for you and allows for SSO if you have the Facebook app installed (much cleaner than using a WebView).

Comment: yes... actually i need to analysis some data after logged into account

Comment: i successfully logged from username, password. but failed in case of facebook login

Comment: If you need to access some data that you can't access via the Facebook API, chances are your app will probably be in breach of Facebook ToS.

Comment: so what is the solution then now

Comment: I believe https://stackoverflow.com/q/12648099/32453

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of October 2013, facebook no longer allows apps to login via custom webviews.

Per [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/26/october-2013-platform-changes/), they want you to use the SDKs.