# What social networks will allow javascript authentication through a custom mobile WebView?

Tags: oauth, webview, facebook-login

I've [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403310/facebook-login-inside-webpage-on-webview-not-working) today, to my surprise, that Facebook [doesn't allow the authentication process to happen in a custom webview anymore](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/26/october-2013-platform-changes/). I need to authenticate users with OAuth, against some sort of widely used social network, and I need to do it in a mobile WebView, using only Javascript (I'm developing WebViews for a Como.com mobile app).

What are the social networks whose API still supports authenticating in a custom mobile WebView?