# Linkedin Login work via browser but not in the WebView

Tags: authentication, oauth, linkedin-api

I've followed the [Linkedin Tutorial to make the login](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api), and tried to include it in my webview.
In the browser it works, in a webview it doesn't.

Why?

Is possible to make the login via linkedin on the webview or is impossibile [as for Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720326/what-social-networks-will-allow-javascript-authentication-through-a-custom-mobil)?

Thank you in advance.

Grace

Answer (score 1):

please try this: this is sample for ignore and skip https

```
   webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
   WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
   settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
   webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
   webView.loadUrl("http://www.Linkedin.com");

   private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                SslError error) {
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            handler.proceed();
        }
    }
```