# F.B sign-in not working in android 5.1 webview

Tags: android, facebook, android-webview

So this is what ive done so far..

Create a webview app that shows a fb sign-in page on my website. I was able to add views dynamically during Fb sign-in as showed in [Making facebook login work with an Android Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648099/making-facebook-login-work-with-an-android-webview) . Everything was working fine (in kitkat- where i usually test my code).

Then, I observed some time ago that in lollipop devices- on clicking the signin button- although a new tab is created and signin occurs successfully, the parent webview is not getting the successful sign-in info.(??). It is still displaying a 'please sign in message'.

I read in some blog long ago that this is a bug in FB api(although im not sure i understood it correctly), and it will be fixed. Has anyone else had the same problem?? .Thanks for ur time.
P.S. My code is similar to the one in the link i referred above.

Comment: You need to provide more information on the error you are seeing , perhaps some code snippets and more info on the "bug" you are referring to.

Comment: @lamdadj22 I think my problem is similar to-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403310/facebook-login-inside-webpage-on-webview-not-working . I'll move to fb android sdk. May be that'll solve such problems.