# How to login with facebook using JS API from WebView

Tags: javascript, facebook, qt, webview

I want to login with `FaceBook` from mobile devices(`WebView`).
I'm trying to login using the example from this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web

But I'm getting the following error

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

According this [manual](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow), I must using faked `redirect_uri` for oauth service to login from `WebView`

> https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

Now, connection string looks like this

> https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=188978851312862&domain=&origin=1&redirect_uri=http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=29#cb=fc2b211fc&domain=&origin=file%3A%2F%2F%2Ff3b6d7ef1c&relation=parent&response_type=token,signed_request,code&sdk=joey

And if you go to this link, you will get the error. But if i change `redirect_uri` to this

> https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=188978851312862&domain=&origin=1&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&domain=&origin=file%3A%2F%2F%2Ff3b6d7ef1c&relation=parent&response_type=token,signed_request,code&sdk=joey

It will succeed.

Is it possible to set faked redirect uri and use standart [JS API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web#quickstart)?

**UPD:** Actually authorizing complete well, but the API's event (auth.authResponseChange) doesn't fires. The problem in `origin` parameter in `redirect_uri` which is set to `file://` when I loginnig from mobile's WebView.

Comment: post your code please!

Comment: I'm using the example of code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web#quickstart

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the advice to, if you're in a WebView, "redirect to https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" is so that it will redirect there, with some auth keys "also in the url" and then you can parse them and close your WebView, so basically a one time callout, FWIW.  My other guess is that origin is there, but not actually checked or used by them [?]

In terms of "using the standard JS API" I think you can but it's [non trivial see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068076/32453).

Answer (score -1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0 Are you using this? If you need any more help give me a buzz, just made one of these