# android webview Facebook login give me blank page

Tags: android, facebook, webview, facebook-login

i have webview.

in my webview i have button to login with facebook account.

when i click on this it move to facebook login...after i write my detiles it go to blank page!

in safari this button work well!!

anyone can help me !?

this my 
MainActivity.java :

```
package com.com.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        String url="http://www.google.com";
        initWebView(webView,url);
         // TODO input your url

    }

    private final static Object methodInvoke(Object obj, String method, Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object[] args) {
        try {
            Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod(method, new Class[] { boolean.class });
            m.invoke(obj, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    private void initWebView(WebView view, String url) {

        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView); // i add this maybe this a problem
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginState", new Class[] { PluginState.class }, new Object[] { PluginState.ON });
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });

        view.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        view.clearHistory();
        view.clearFormData();
        view.clearCache(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);

        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);


            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                                      Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                dialog.setMessage("loading...");
                dialog.show();
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // i add this maybe this a problem


                dialog.dismiss();
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }
        });

        view.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        // webView.setDownloadListener(downloadListener);

    }
```

Comment: Have anyone resolved this issue?

Comment: For those who are still looking for a solution, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068076/1188004)