# Facebook login message: "URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor, oauth

Important notice:

If you register for testing, go to your profile settings and to your **interests** add **delete profile**.

Trying to login with Facebook to my [website](http://openstrategynetwork.com/):

I get the following error:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and
>   Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs.

My `settings` (Basics) in Facebook are:

- App Domains: openstrategynetwork.com
- Site URL for `website`: http://openstrategynetwork.com/

In the advanced tab, `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` is set to:

`http://openstrategynetwork.com/_oauth/facebook?close`

App is `public`.

More settings (Advanced) here:
[image]

App key and secret are correct. I'm using Meteor and its accounts packages.

Comment: What's your ROOT_URL?

Comment: What url are you using to redirect to the Facebook sign in page? You still need to specify the redirect_uri in the authorization request.

Comment: @aedm: ROOT_URL is set to ```http://openstrategynetwork.com```

Comment: @EdwardJiang: where can I do that? It's strange as it once was working for localhost. But even localhost is not working anymore.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue also, redirect_uri matches exactly to the config in Client OAuth Settings - see more on https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/232085950706415/ need help anyone.. thanks in advance

Comment: I've a webapp which generates variable redirect URIs to pass some parameters, I guess I'm screwed? What about whitelisting a domain to allow all sort of URIs under it?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The login with Facebook button on your site is linking to:

`https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=1500708243571026&redirect_uri=http://openstrategynetwork.com/_oauth/facebook&display=popup&scope=email&state=eyJsb2dpblN0eWxlIjoicG9wdXAiLCJjcmVkZW50aWFsVG9rZW4iOiIwSXhEU05XamJjU0VaQWdqcmF6SXdOUWRuRFozXzc0X19lbVhGWUJTZGNYIiwiaXNDb3Jkb3ZhIjpmYWxzZX0=`

Notice: `redirect_uri=http://openstrategynetwork.com/_oauth/facebook`

If you instead change the link to:

`redirect_uri=http://openstrategynetwork.com/_oauth/facebook?close`

It should work. Or, you can change the Facebook link to `http://openstrategynetwork.com/_oauth/facebook`

You can also add `http://localhost/_oauth/facebook` to the valid redirect URIs.

Facebook requires that you whitelist redirect URIs, since otherwise people could login with Facebook for your service, and then send their access token to an attacker's server! And you don't want that to happen ;]

Comment: What exactly is a OAuth redirect URI? I would expect this to be the same URL as the root web app.

Comment: This seems to work. Although Im not sure if it was not originally as I was trying to log in with the account that I have the app created under. Implemented this solution, and used a different account and it worked (seemingly). The language and info on oAuth redirect URIs needs to be clear. The info is quit esoteric and almost arcane. Terms used aren't even defined or clarified.

Comment: thanks so much fixed my issue! even though i got ssl working

Comment: The trick is to look at the redirect url and add that to the "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" in my case thats signin-facebook.

Comment: 1. make sure to add with and without www urls to your *Valid Auth redirect URIs*

Comment: My redirect URL is https://${base_url}/#/fb-confirm
Why this hash is causing a problem in this

Answer (score 128):

As the questioner writes

> In the advanced tab, Valid OAuth redirect URIs is set to: ...

and I had the same problem (writing the redirect url into the wrong input field) I would like to highlight that

**It's NOT**

```
Settings -> Advanced -> Share Redirect Whitelist
```

**but**

```
Facebook Login -> Settings -> Valid OAuth redirect URIs
```

It would have saved me 2 hours of trial and error.

You should also have it in mind that 
`www.example.com` is not the same as `example.com`. Add both formats to the redirect URL.

Comment: Down-voters: please add a comment about your concerns, otherwise the answer wont get better.

Comment: Jesus, i spent so much time looking in the wrong place, thank you.

Comment: Trying to add a new URI I get: `New HTTP Redirect URIs are not allowed` :(

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried everything, but at wrong place. What does "Share Redirect Whitelist" means?

Comment: This is the answer for me. Also you want to go to `Settings -> Advanced -> Security -> Server IP Allow List` if Facebook complains about IP

Comment: im fortunate to have run into your answer before spending two hours, which I likely would have! Thank you!

Comment: WHY can't I upvote one answer 1000 times?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Hey Benny, I'm somewhat confused as to how I should get the redirect URL. I.e I'm not 100% sure what it is since I cannot see it. Any idea on where I would get it?

Comment: @DCoderT you are free to choose your redirect URL. A user will get redirected to this URL when the OAuth process (Log in) is finished

Answer (score 30):

This worked for me.

`redirect_url = http://127.0.0.1:8080/accounts/facebook/login/callback/`

I got that from my browser after clicking the Facebook button you browser will be redirected to a link for integrating with Facebook API, so where you will get that redirect. For my case the link was this from where I got the redirect_url.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=...&scope=&response_type=code&state=...&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/accounts/facebook/login/callback/

[image]
[image]

Comment: For my MVC application, I had to add "/signin-facebook" to the site url....thanks for the wonderful tip!

Comment: You save my weeks @Umar Asghar

Comment: Spent too long on this. Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 12):

Make sure "**App Domain**" and **Facebook Login => Valid OAuth redirect URIs**. There you must check **www** or **without www**. Its better if you use with www or without for all URLs in php,html,css files and Fb app settings.

Other thing is if you're using "/" end of the URLs you must add that URL to app settings of **Valid OAuth redirect URIs**.
Example:- https://www.example.com/index.php/   if this url if youre using in the redirect url you must set that to app settings.

Hope this would be help.

Comment: in app domain you add both with and without www

Comment: What do you mean by this post friend I'm kinda confused.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I just had to make sure I have my urls both with and without **www** for *Application Domain* and *Redirect URLs*:

[image]

In my case, I had to use: `signin-facebook` after my site url, for redirect url.

Comment: Are App Domains really needed? When I tested locally, it worked without setting App Domains

Comment: Do you use oAuth, and redirection?

Comment: yes. I use symfony bundle https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle

Answer (score 8):

Ok First of all this is a very clear error message. Just look at this many devs miss this including my self. Have a look at the screen shot here please.

[image]

### Under Products > Facebook Login > Settings

or just go to this url here (Replace YOUR_APP_ID with your app id lol):

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/fb-login/settings/
```

If you are working on `localhost:3000` Make sure you have `https://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback`

Ofcourse you don't have to have the status live (Green Switch on top right corner) but in my case, I am deploying to heroku now and will soon replace `localhost:3000` with `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/auth/facebook/callback`

Of course I will update the urls in Settings/Basic & Settings/Advanced and also add a privacy policy url in the basic section.

I am assuming that you have properly configured initializers/devise.rb  if you are using devise and you have the proper facebook `gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 4.0'` gem installed and `gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.6'`, and you have the necessary columns in your users table such as uid, image, and provider. That's it.

Answer (score 7):

For my Node Application,

```
"facebook": {
        "clientID" : "##############",
        "clientSecret": "####################",
        "callbackURL": "/auth/facebook/callback/"
    }
```

**put callback Url relative**

My OAuth redirect URIs as follows

[image]

Make Sure  ***"/"*** at the end of Facebook auth redirect URI

These setups worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Changing from **hauth.done=Facebook** to **hauth_done=Facebook** in the Valid OAuth redirect URIs fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

### Hey Guys

##### so i was having this error below[image]

##### Basically all you have to do is to make sure your url in "OAuth Redirect URIs" from facebook corresponds with your url callback in your code see the image sample below

[image: code]

#### !!!must match with this below

[image]

If error still persist make sure this 3(three) URL are  correct!.

- Site URL
- Privacy Policy URL
- App domains

you can view them in your developer->settings->basic tab.

hope this helps you fix the bug! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add http://openstrategynetwork.com/**sigin-facebook** to Client OAuth Settings valid redirect URL along with your own redirect URL.

Answer (score 1):

It might help somebody.

I had the similar error message, but only in dev and staging environments, not in production. The valid redirect URIs were correctly set, for the dev and staging subdomains as well as for production.

It turned out I forgot that for those environments we use the testing FB app, which is a separate one in the FB developer page. Had to select that and update its settings.

Answer (score 0):

Login Helper of your site

$loginUrl       = $helper->getLoginUrl('xyz.com/user_by_facebook/', $permissions);

and in facebook application dashboard  (Under products tab  : **Facebook Login** )

**Valid OAuth redirect URIs** should also be same to xyz.com/user_by_facebook/

as mentioned earlier while making request from web

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, such a nightmare.

1. Make sure your App IDs and Secret Keys are correct. If you are using separate development, staging and production apps for testing, the App IDs and Secret Keys are all different for each app. This is often the problem.
2. Make sure you have the callback URL set properly in your app config file (see below). And then add this as same URL under "*Facebook Login*" settings where it says "*Valid OAuth redirect URIs*". It should look like this (depending on your environment):

`http://localhost/auth/facebook/callback`
`http://staging.example.com/auth/facebook/callback`
`http://example.com/auth/facebook/callback`

3. Make sure your app domain is set to the correct domain for each environment, including both "www" and "no-www". Facebook also requires these domains to match the URL of your website or app platform. You will have to select "*Add Platform*" to add this.

Comment: requirement of matching redirect URIs  with the URL of website is not possible for me because my redirect URIs or defined on another server and my website is served from different server, hwo can i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was integrating Facebook login within a Rails app tutorial. I had added http://localhost:3000/adsf to my Valid OAuth Redirect URIs, but the Rails app would open the url as http://0.0.0.0:3000 and would therefore try to redirect to http://0.0.0.0:3000/asdf. After adding http://0.0.0.0:3000/asdf to the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs, or navigating to http://localhost:3000/asdf, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case URI, as it was defined on FB, was fine, but I was using Spring Security and it was adding **;jsessionid=0B9A5E71DAA32A01A3CD351E6CA1FCDD** to my URI so, it caused the mismatching.

```
https://m.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?client_id=your-fb-id-code&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localizator.org/auth/facebook;jsessionid=0B9A5E71DAA32A01A3CD351E6CA1FCDD&scope=email&state=b180578a-007b-48bc-bd81-4b08c6989e18
```

In order to avoid the URL rewriting I added **disable-url-rewriting="true"** to Spring Security config, in this way:

```
<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/security/accessDenied" use-expressions="true"
      disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>
```

And it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add www in redirect_uri in your code.

Like:-
https://www.facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=427141371274449&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/facebook-callback&scope=email&state=5f40cc740267d3-34619096-32051275-123456

Answer (score 0):

so if you dont see the facebook login for business
then goto -> Use cases -> Authentication and account creation (Customise) -> Goto Settings -> add the URL in the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my particular situation, I encountered a rather unique challenge. Despite the fact that my application was still in development mode, I encountered an issue when attempting to include my local redirect URL. Fortunately, I was able to resolve this problem by substituting "https://" in place of "http://".[image]

Answer (score -1):

Put your url here
Facebook Login -> Settings -> Valid OAuth redirect URIs
AND
you'll also get that error if your APP ID is wrong