# facebook login window pops up and immediately closes after

Tags: facebook, meteor, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook's login on http://openstrategynetwork.com/ suddenly doesn't login users anymore. I had an issue before but managed to solve it thanks to Stack Overflow's community:

If this might help: [Facebook login message: "URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001004/facebook-login-message-url-blocked-this-redirect-failed-because-the-redirect)

I'm using **meteor** with **accounts-facebook** and **useraccounts:bootstrap**.

[image]

Comment: API v2.2 was shut down end of March, and with API v2.3 the access token  return format has changed. Go make sure you have the latest versions of the components you are using, and use at least v2.3 in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot.