# “URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings.” But works locally

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have problem like here [Facebook login message: "URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001004/facebook-login-message-url-blocked-this-redirect-failed-because-the-redirect)

[image]

I have checked various answers - cant make it work, and they don't give much new - just practically say to add url to that field.

One of them said to "Make sure your App IDs and Secret Keys are correct."
I found out they were not set, but now admin said he added those so should be ok.

What else to do? How to debug?

"URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs."

It also tells to check Client and Web OAuth to make on, but I have them off to increase security becasue I have read or watched somewhere in facebook documentation. And since login works locally with them turned off, they should be not be needed. I tested by trying to turn them on, but as I expected they don't fix the problem.

**Update:**
Redirect uri parameter is redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Falpha.vop.veracityinsurance.com%2Fconnect%2Ffacebook%2Fcheck

Made a video: https://www.loom.com/share/88e607aece6b45489214d95ee01bbb0b

I have made debug function and pushed it to server which prints provider:

```
$provider = (array)$this->clientRegistry->getClient('facebook_main')->getOAuth2Provider();
        print_r($provider);
```

And from that class I see app id is correct in server.

config.yml

```
knpu_oauth2_client:
    clients:
        # the key "facebook_main" can be anything, it
        # will create a service: "knpu.oauth2.client.facebook_main"
        facebook_main:
            # this will be one of the supported types
            type: facebook
            client_id: '%env(CONFIG__OAUTH__FACEBOOK__ID)%'
            client_secret: '%env(CONFIG__OAUTH__FACEBOOK__SECRET)%'
            # the route that you're redirected to after
            redirect_route: connect_facebook_check
            redirect_params: {}
            graph_api_version: v5.0
```

Btw I am using symfony bundle for integration https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle

Comment: Of course you need Client OAuth  Login and Web OAuth Login set to on … logging in via the web is what you are trying to do after all, no?

Comment: When do you get the message, when the login dialog is about to be shown, or afterwards, when the code is to be exchanged for a token? What is the exact value of the redirect_uri parameter in your login dialog call? (Check browser address bar.)

Comment: @04FS - why of course? It works on my machine. I also logging in via web on my machine.

Comment: @04FS - there is no login dialog in my case. There is just link clicked by user which goes to my method. Then my method redirects to facebook. I am using this bundle : https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle

Comment: Of course, because that’s exactly what they are _for_. I can’t tell you why what should not even work with these turned off, seems to work “on your machine”, because you have given is very little info so far about what you are actually doing. (Or perhaps you are still using a different app id than you think.)

Comment: redirect_uri looks okay, seems to match what your screenshot shows. Check if the app id value is a match as well.

Comment: @04FS added video, maybe will make more clear

Comment: No, it doesn’t. I know what the error “looks like”, and this does not contain any additional, actually useful info.

Comment: @04FS - updated post, app id is correct in server. Is there anything else I should add?

Comment: Do you have the necessary settings set to on now? What is your app id (first couple of digits and last couple of digits, doesn’t have to be the full one)?

Comment: Have tried again setting those to on. When setting one of them, I earlier had error, but I did not look at it because locally it worked with those settings on. 
@04FS Now I fixed this error (it was php version problem) and it works with only turnining on Web OAuth Login. 
Client OAuth Login is off. Can you explain - how it could work locally with both settings off? It does not make sense still. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it work as 04FS said to turn on settings. It was enought to turn on one of them only - Web OAuth Login.

[image]