# Azure Functions and Facebook login

Tags: facebook, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-functions

I am trying to figure out how to use Azure Function with Facebook login using the EasyAuth but when I try to access my app I keep getting the following error:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and
>   Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs.

On the Facebook developer page I have added in the Facebook Login product and under the option 
**Valid OAuth Redirect URIs** I inserted the following urls

```
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net
```

and the options **Client OAuth Login** and **Web OAuth Login** are both on.

In the Azure portal for the Azure Function I have added the Facebook login under MyApp / Authentication / Authorization

Is there something else I need to configure to make this work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001004/facebook-login-message-url-blocked-this-redirect-failed-because-the-redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce your issue with the same error message.

[image]

In the **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** field, just enter the url with `https://<app-name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback` and it will work well. Remember to replace `<app-name>` with the name of your Azure App Service app.

For more details, you could refer to this article to [Configure your App Service app to use Facebook login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-facebook).