# Facebook login message: “URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Trying to login to my [website](https://www.templeconnect.com/login)

But Getting error 
[image: But getting this error]

I have followed the steps given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001004/facebook-login-message-url-blocked-this-redirect-failed-because-the-redirect)

Also, I have added Valid Redirect URL in FB app settings, please check image below:
[image: error]

What could be issue here?

Comment: pretty sure you don't mean `fblogin&scope=email`. You probably want `fblogin?scope=email`. Both for the URL you redirect to and for the URL you whitelist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `redirect_uri` parameter in your first screenshot is `https://www.templeconnect.com/fblogin`, so *that* is what needs to be put into your app settings.

---

The `&scope=email` part is not part of *your* redirect URL, but part of the “outer” URL that calls the FB login dialog here. `scope` is a parameter of *that* URL, same way as `redirect_uri` is.