# Facebook Web OAuth URL Login blocked because URL is not whitelisted

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have implemented a method for users to sign up an account using facebooK Web OAuth Login but when a user tries to sign up I get this below error, I have enabled Client and Web OAuth Login and the valid redirect URL but I am still getting this error. I have also looked over the previous Stack Overflow posts from here [Facebook login message: "URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001004/facebook-login-message-url-blocked-this-redirect-failed-because-the-redirect) and practically tried all the steps to no avail.

[image: Facebook error]
[image: Facebook settings]

Comment: Which URL are you trying to redirect to?

Comment: @wizkid https://www.workfleek.co.ke/

Comment: No, that is not the actual value of the `redirect_uri` parameter used in your login dialog call. `https://workfleek.co.ke/fb-callback` would be the correct one to input into that field, according to the login dialog URL your site is currently creating.