# URL blocked: "Add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs" (with a Facebook Business App)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk

Trying to get Facebook Login to work with my next-auth / nextjs app.

It all works *when I select a `Consumer App`* and it's in Development Mode.

However, I want to use features of the App Type `Business App`. Business Apps in Facebook don't have Development Mode / Production Mode. Instead, everything is managed via access levels. The first 2 types in this list is what I am referring to:

[image]

Now, when I try it out with a Consumer App, things work fine. It does not work for me however when I use a Business App. I get the following error:

> URL blocked This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
> white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the
> client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as
> valid OAuth redirect URIs.

[image]

However, I cannot add the URL to valid OAuth redirect URIs, since Facebook tells me that localhost is automatically approved in development mode, so I doesn't allow me to add it. But this is weird, since [there is no 'development mode' for business apps.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-modes/)

See these 2 images:

[image]

[image]

I found that a bit strange, so I deployed it to production and tested it - this works.

So Consumer App + localhost works, Business App + Localhost **doesn't** work, Business App + Production works.

Does anyone know what the problem is with localhost + business apps on facebook? I would really love to test things in development, and not have to push everything to production all the time.

Comment: You can try and add a domain name to your local test setup, so that you can access your project via `myproject.local` or something. Then it should allow you to save Valid OAuth Redirect URIs. But then you will probably also need working SSL, I think `localhost` is the only exception left.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is trying to use shaHmac512 to encrypt and sign your token, digesting with hex

I do remember having to do this for auth from localhost

and to gain access to "long-lived" access tokens for facebook business/facebook for developers

```
const accessToken = process.env.FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN ?? "";
const secretKey = process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET ?? "";


function signHmacSha512(key: string, secret: string) {
  key = accessToken;
  secret = secretKey;
  const hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha512", key);
  const signed = hmac.update(Buffer.from(secret, "utf-8")).digest("hex");
  return signed;
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(signHmacSha512(accessToken, secretKey), null, 2));
```

no promises it will definitely work, I did this before they became meta in the past 9 months

might be worth checking out this thread though
[Facebook login message: "URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001004/facebook-login-message-url-blocked-this-redirect-failed-because-the-redirect?rq=1)