# Do google plus and linkedIn shared login allow login from android app webview?

Tags: android, authentication, webview, google-plus, linkedin-api

We have a website and provide shared login with linkedIn and google plus accounts.
Do google plus and linkedIn allow login from android app webview?
Or we have to implement native login via sdk and server provides APIs to complete login process?

Thanks in advance!
Leon

Comment: Check this answer, a guy in comment confirm that he is login from google plus. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19068076/5154783

Comment: @shahzainali Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make google plus and linkedIn login provided by website work in webview. The key point is that google login javascript opens a new window when initializing a session for authentication with google server. I create a new webview for google login page. We need to keep website login page open which initialises the google authentication, and once google authenticates user successfully, we close the new webview . After that website login webview receives callback and proceed user to login.
It is similar to linkedIn and FB login flow.