# Problems with WebView and facebook comments login

Tags: android, webview

I finished building a WebView app for my blog, but I'm struggling with the comment forms of the blog posts...

A blog post has a Facebook Comment form and Disqus form for comments, when a user logs in with his account (facebook or disqus) to comment on the blog post, the WebView goes blank, the LogCat shows the following:

```
06-12 01:41:23.161 25469-25469/com.lfcchile I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://www.liverpoolecho.co.uk') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://login.liverpoolecho.co.uk').", source:  (0)
06-12 01:41:23.670 25469-25469/com.lfcchile I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.", source:  (0)
06-12 01:41:24.173 25469-25469/com.lfcchile I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(157)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null", source: http://login.liverpoolecho.co.uk/GS/GSLogin.aspx?state=mt%3Df_ZBY0aurAv1MxAfZR5z-zz-ETcKtpdXvVcPwVbv46Q.&code=4/lKuWs2HMelOHr7GrjjGa4_LhJiXKK2U15XFuFDZ0R-Y&authuser=0&session_state=d1a06bba2ecd9f8532bc57754cc167dc55368b39..6516&prompt=consent (157)
06-12 01:50:51.942 25469-25469/com.lfcchile I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closed' of null", source: https://m.facebook.com/plugins/close_popup.php?reload=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fplugins%2Fcomments.php%3Fapi_key%3D1043577742379358%26channel_url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fstaticxx.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Fxd_arbiter.php%253Fversion%253D42%2523cb%253Df27a5826d3620f%2526domain%253Dlfcchile.com%2526origin%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Flfcchile.com%25252Ff26fe3ca59041dc%2526relation%253Dparent.parent%26colorscheme%3Dlight%26href%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flfcchile.com%252F2016%252F05%252F24%252Ftenemos-nuevo-portero-loris-karius%252F%26locale%3Des_LA%26mobile%3Dtrue%26numposts%3D1%26sdk%3Djoey%26skin%3Dlight%26version%3Dv2.3%26refsrc%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flfcchile.com%252F2016%252F05%252F24%252Ftenemos-nuevo-portero-loris-karius%252F%26ret%3Doptin%26order_by%3Dtime%26hash%3DAQAX5nrCJZbrqaQQ (1)
```

My MainActivity

```
package com.lfcchile;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private WebView myWebView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    //Función que almacena la URL actual para compartirla
    private void shareURL() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myWebView.getUrl());
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Comparte este enlace!"));
    }

    //Función que chequea si la App de WordPress está instalada en el dispositivo
    public void checkApp() {
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("org.wordpress.android");
        boolean installed = appInstalledOrNot("org.wordpress.android");
        if (installed) {
            //Se abre la App
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            //Redirecciona a Play Store para instalar la App
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Necesitas tener instalada la App de WordPress",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "org.wordpress.android"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    //Función para mostrar más Apps del mismo desarrollador
    public void developerProfile() {
        final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://developer?id=J.+Llorente")));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=J.+Llorente")));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                shareURL();
            }
        });

        this.myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webViewInicio);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webViewInicio);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        // Propiedades del WebView
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://lfcchile.com/");

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    //Controlar lo que el botón "Atrás" hace
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            if (this.myWebView.canGoBack())
                this.myWebView.goBack();
            else
                super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    //Funciones que permiten iconos en la Action Bar del MainActivity
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //Acciones de los botones de la Action Bar
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //Acción de botón Salir
        if (id == R.id.action_salir) {
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nos vemos pronto! YNWA!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //Acción del botón Recargar
        if (id == R.id.action_recargar) {
            myWebView.reload();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Acciones del menú.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_inicio) {
            setTitle(R.string.inicio);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://lfcchile.com/");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_destacado) {
            setTitle(R.string.destacado);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://lfcchile.com/category/destacado/");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tabla_pl) {
            setTitle(R.string.tabla_pl);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://lfcchile.com/tabla-pl/");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_hillsborough) {
            setTitle(R.string.hillsborough);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://lfcchile.com/hillsborough/");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sitiosinteres) {
            setTitle(R.string.sitiosinteres);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://lfcchile.com/sitios-interes/");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_comunidad) {
            setTitle(R.string.comunidad);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://lfcchile.com/comunidad/");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_wordpress) {
            checkApp();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_playstore) {
            developerProfile();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed = false;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            app_installed = true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            app_installed = false;
        }
        return app_installed;
    }

    //Controla las acciones al cargar la pagina y al finalizar carga
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // Sitios web que se cargan dentro de la app, los demás abren el navegador del telefono
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Jonathan. Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to Disqus, but the login process for Facebook Comments requires that you create a separate `WebView` -- or, a separate "window", in JavaScript terms. (I suspect Disqus is similar, given the symptom you're seeing.) The error `Cannot read property 'closed' of null` is due to the fact that WebSettings defaults mutli-window support to false. In the section with the comment `// Propiedades del WebView`, you need to add:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

However, I see that you have some other issues here, as well. For instance, for Lollipop and later, you need to allow third-party cookies, so that the Facebook token can be accessed from the `WebView` that hosts comments. I use this helper method. In your case, you would pass in `myWebView`:

```
public static void setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(WebView webView, boolean accept) {
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

    if (accept && !cookieManager.acceptCookie()) {
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    }
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, accept);
    }
}
```

You will also need to assign a subclass of `WebChromeClient` to `myWebView`, and within your subclass you must override `onCreateWindow()`, as documented here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setSupportMultipleWindows(boolean). Within that method, you will need to create a second `WebView`, to host Facebook's login screen, and send the `android.os.Message` object passed into `onCreateWindow()` to the newly created target `WebView`.

To get a complete picture of all that is entailed, I suggest you refer to the answers to this question about handling Facebook's web login: [Making facebook login work with an Android Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12648099/315702).