# facebook and WhatsApp not appearing in "complete action using:" list when started from my app

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to start the facebook app or the WhastApp app from my own app but they wont appear in the "Complete action using:" list

I have

```
Intent intentFB = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intentFB.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.facebook"));
intentFB.putExtra("ClassName","FB");
intentFB.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
intentFB.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intentFB.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intentFB);
```

Basiclly I have a webview with a page with an article. This page has a facebook link to share the article. When I tap the link the list appear without the facebook option

Comment: Have this apps are *installed* on your device ?

Comment: Yes of coruse, I have them installed

Comment: What exactly is happening explain bit more.

Comment: I added a comment at the bottom of the post to expand my explanation

Comment: Not sure may be this link will be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648099/making-facebook-login-work-with-an-android-webview