# facebook login is not working in webview

Tags: android, webview, facebook-login

I have a webview in my app which opens various websites which have login linked with Facebook google etc. They all open a new window for login purposes and close them afterwards.
In my app windows is opening but not closing. It gets blank out and in log i get string "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it"
with this message i can get that my webview is not able to close popped up window.

Can you please let me now how to handle this?
Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: why not add your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19068076/6028746