# React-Native Webview and Facebook Login Not working

Tags: android, webview, react-native, facebook-login

I have a problem with react-native webview app and Facebook login via modal window.
The login works on mobile browsers but when I try to login via app I see white screen.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on login button on my site.
2. Enter username and password on FB modal window and submit the form
3. See white screen

I think the problem is the same like this one [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648099/making-facebook-login-work-with-an-android-webview) but I do not know how I can handle that using react-native.

Can anybody help me how can I handle that problem using react-native?

Comment: You should really show some code. Anything is better than nothing. Also - are you getting any errors in your `react-native log-android` or `adb logcat` logs?