# Unsafe JavaScript URL initiate navigation for frame

Tags: java, android, webview

I've been trying to implement a facebook login on a webview in android. I've searched and searched, and can't find anything that works. The latest thing I've tried is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068076/1944429 . It's got a lot of up votes, but it's not working for me.

I get `"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'https://m.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth?app_id=...' from frame with URL 'http://www.example.com/example/'. The frame attempting navigation is neither same-origin with the target, nor is it the target's parent or opener.` and a blank white screen.

The error appears in Logcat. It makes sense, that webview can only display one window, and the solution was a work around with a second webview.

I don't know how to fix the error though. Is there anyway to link the two webviews together, or make one a parent webview, so I don't get the error? I really want to get this working.

Comment: So did it work for you finally?

Comment: nope, gave up on it