# Use facebook smartphone App to login in Captive Portal auth page

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-login, captiveportal

Is there a way to use mobile apps **Facebook** (Apple, Android, etc ...) to automatically authenticate users who wish to use social access for the Captive Guest-Wifi portal or similar services?

I worked with the *standard* social login authentication module of the standard captive portal which intercepts the first call of the operating system (*Captive Portal Assistant*) or the standard browser (Chrome, Safari, FF, etc ...), but this means that a user must know his credentials.

It could be easier to use the App where the customer is already logged in...
thanks!

Comment: At first, you have to accept `facebook.com` or any domains that facebook login needs in order to get clients access to a facebook login page like google login and OAuth2. Next, on the splash page, add a button to access users to get on a login page of facebook.

Comment: Thanks @M.Rostami but what I'm looking for is to use Facebook Mobile App not a general Facebook Social Login OAuth, is it possible?

Comment: I'm not an android developer, although, you can call an application when a user wants to open a domain name. I'm not sure but it's a "redirecting" method.

Comment: Ok, but I need to authenticate the facebook user not to only open Facebook App.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to authenticate the facebook user not to only open Facebook App.

To do it, check [this link - *Facebook Login for Android*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/)  out. It would help you.

Also, in [this question - *Making facebook login work with an Android Webview*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648099/making-facebook-login-work-with-an-android-webview) there is a method to create a Facebook login button with their javascript API.

The problem that you may face is "Android captive portal's splash page limitation". The splash page has a lot of limitations on js codes.
After that, if you faced this kind of problem, create a redirect page for the splash page and on the redirected page, you can do anything you want as a normal web page.