# How to access data of default browser from web app

Tags: java, android

I have a website. I have converted it to android app via java webview. The website has the option to login with Facebook and Google. But this option can't work webapp

I have used some code which makes it possible to login with facebook but it has to login separately. Login is not happening in other apps

Comment: check this please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068076